# Entity Framework Core - update related collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update collection of ProjectEmployees inside ProjectModel.
I want to remove all old values and set new.

My models:

```
public class Project
{
    ... 
    public ICollection<ProjectEmployee> ProjectEmployees { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectEmployee
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class ProjectGroupModel //ViewModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> ProjectEmployees { get; set; }
}
```

It's typical many-to-many relationship.

My controller action:

```
    [HttpPost("group")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateGroup([FromBody] ProjectGroupModel pro)
    {
            var dbProject = await _context.Project
                .Include(p=>p.ProjectEmployees)
                .FirstAsync(p => p.ProjectId == pro.ProjectId);
            dbProject.ProjectEmployees.Clear();

            foreach (var emp in pro.ProjectEmployees)
            {
                dbProject.ProjectEmployees.Add(new ProjectEmployee()
                {
                    UserId = emp.UserId
                });
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();
    }
```

When pro.ProjectEmployees is empty all records from dbProject.ProjectEmployees were removed correctly, also if dbProject.ProjectEmployees is empty new records from model were added, but when dbProject.ProjectEmployees is not empty I can't set new records:

ERROR:

> "The instance of entity type 'ProjectEmployee' cannot be tracked
>   because another instance of this type with the same key is already
>   being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique
>   temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key
>   property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are
>   explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not
>   collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other
>   new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context."

I tried to repair this action in a hundreds way but always sth is wrong.

Comment: should convert dbProject  to list using ToList method. and then try to update it

Comment: It seems to me like primary key conflicts. When you create new ProjectEmployee() you only set the UserId. Shouldn't you also set ProjectId?

Comment: What is the PK for `ProjectEmployee`?

Comment: @MuhammadNasir I'm fetching one record of Project, where I should use ToList() ?

Comment: @JakubRusilko I don't think so, as I said when dbProject.ProjectEmployees is empty new records are added corectly.

Comment: @IvanStoev ProjectId and UserId are both PK. It's associative entity

Comment: use FirstOrDefaultAsync then

Comment: @MuhammadNasir it's not a problem. I'm sure that dbProject is not null

Comment: @Kuba So that's the problem - see the error message *because **another instance** of this type with **the same key** is already being tracked*

Comment: @IvanStoev I understand, I'm trying to delete all rows connected with this project before adding new but I'm still geting this error.

Comment: @Kuba And that's seems to be a problem to EF Core. since you don't call `SaveChanges`, the "deleted" entities are still tracked, i.e. not considered deleted, so once you add an entity with the same PK, boom :)

Comment: @Kuba, have you tried what I suggested in my answer below?

Comment: @IvanStoev I considered this earlier. I added extra SaveChanges directly after calling Clear() but problem still exist :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's far from perfect, but the only way I was able to make it work is to remove the items from the corresponding `DbSet` and call `SaveChanges` before adding the new ones:

```cs
    var dbProject = await _context.Project
        .Include(p=>p.ProjectEmployees)
        .FirstAsync(p => p.ProjectId == pro.ProjectId);

    if (dbProject.ProjectEmployees.Any())
    {
        _context.ProjectEmployee.RemoveRange(dbProject.ProjectEmployees);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    foreach (var emp in pro.ProjectEmployees)
    {
        dbProject.ProjectEmployees.Add(new ProjectEmployee()
        {
            UserId = emp.UserId
        });
    }
    
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: At the moment I don't care if its perfect, casuse it works! Thanks so much. It was't worth looking for the ideal solution. I wasted a lot of time for that. Sometimes the simplest ways are the best ;)

Comment: And what is the optimal solution? I have the save feeling that there should be definitely something better.

Answer (score 4):

linked to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993860/entity-framework-core-update-many-to-many)

I can answer it here with your classes.

Then use this extension i made to remove the unselected and add the newly selected to the list

```
    public static void TryUpdateManyToMany<T, TKey>(this DbContext db, IEnumerable<T> currentItems, IEnumerable<T> newItems, Func<T, TKey> getKey) where T : class
    {
        db.Set<T>().RemoveRange(currentItems.Except(newItems, getKey));
        db.Set<T>().AddRange(newItems.Except(currentItems, getKey));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other, Func<T, TKey> getKeyFunc)
    {
        return items
            .GroupJoin(other, getKeyFunc, getKeyFunc, (item, tempItems) => new { item, tempItems })
            .SelectMany(t => t.tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty(), (t, temp) => new { t, temp })
            .Where(t => ReferenceEquals(null, t.temp) || t.temp.Equals(default(T)))
            .Select(t => t.t.item);
    }
```

using it looks like this

```
 var model = db.Employees
             .Include(x => x.ProjectEmployees)
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeId == employee.EmployeeId);

 db.TryUpdateManyToMany(model.ProjectEmployees, listOfNewProjectIds
 .Select(x => new ProjectEmployee
 {
     ProjectId = x,
     EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeId
 }), x => x.ProjectId );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the old objects are not really removed from the database. You are only calling Clear() which is not enough. Try doing this:

```
[HttpPost("group")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateGroup([FromBody] ProjectGroupModel pro)
{
    var dbProject = await _context.Project
        .Include(p=>p.ProjectEmployees)
        .FirstAsync(p => p.ProjectId == pro.ProjectId);

    foreach (var old in dbProject.ProjectEmployees)
        {
            _context.ProjectEmployee.Remove(old);
        }

    dbProject.ProjectEmployees.Clear();

    foreach (var emp in pro.ProjectEmployees)
        {
            dbProject.ProjectEmployees.Add(new ProjectEmployee()
            {
                UserId = emp.UserId
            });
        }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok();
}
```

Here I assume that you have the proper set in your context (_context.ProjectEmployee). If you don't have this Set explicitly in your context just add it.

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately it returns the same error. I'm sure that Clear() works fine cause when pro.ProjectEmployee is empty db collection is cleared.

Comment: The collection in memory is cleared. But, please, check if the records are really deleted from the database. Can you confirm this?

Comment: They are. I think that as IvanStoev said it's problem with ef change tracking. Even if rows are deleted it doesn't know about that

Comment: change the State of the object to be deleted