# Entity framework core update many to many

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

We are porting our existing MVC6 EF6 application to Core.

Is there a simple method in EF Core to update a many-to-many relationship?

My old code from EF6 where we clear the list and overwrite it with the new data no longer works.

```
var model = await _db.Products.FindAsync(vm.Product.ProductId);
model.Colors.Clear();
model.Colors =  _db.Colors.Where(x => 
vm.ColorsSelected.Contains(x.ColorId)).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean by no longer works?

Comment: It no longer produces the expected result. Entity framework core does change tracking differently.

Comment: I had a similar issue, tried the various answers below and in the end fixed it by making sure I was calling `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` on the child collection (`Colors` in your example). Much simpler. This article is also useful: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/updating-many-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-core/

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "no longer works". Just replacing the relationships is the easiest way to do this if the number of relationships is limited and it's possible to do this using EF core.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This will work for you.

Make a class to have the relationship in:

```
public class ColorProduct
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }

    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Add a `ColorProduct` collection to your `Product` and `Color` classes:

```
 public ICollection<ColorProduct> ColorProducts { get; set; }
```

Then use this extension I made to remove the unselected and add the newly selected to the list:

```
public static void TryUpdateManyToMany<T, TKey>(this DbContext db, IEnumerable<T> currentItems, IEnumerable<T> newItems, Func<T, TKey> getKey) where T : class
{
    db.Set<T>().RemoveRange(currentItems.Except(newItems, getKey));
    db.Set<T>().AddRange(newItems.Except(currentItems, getKey));
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other, Func<T, TKey> getKeyFunc)
{
    return items
        .GroupJoin(other, getKeyFunc, getKeyFunc, (item, tempItems) => new { item, tempItems })
        .SelectMany(t => t.tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty(), (t, temp) => new { t, temp })
        .Where(t => ReferenceEquals(null, t.temp) || t.temp.Equals(default(T)))
        .Select(t => t.t.item);
}
```

Using it looks like this:

```
var model = _db.Products
    .Include(x => x.ColorProducts)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductId == vm.Product.ProductId);

_db.TryUpdateManyToMany(model.ColorProducts, vm.ColorsSelected
    .Select(x => new ColorProduct
    {
        ColorId = x,
        ProductId = vm.Product.ProductId
    }), x => x.ColorId);
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. I can use this extension in all of my projects. Thank you for your timely answer.

Comment: The critical part of this solution (and the problem in the OP code) is the `Include` call.

Comment: AddRange doesn't have Func<T, TKey> getKey parameter

Comment: Is it a good and efficient way? Or did you find any possible other way?

Comment: Why checking for the equality of null and default? I guess only default is sufficient (as the default for ref types can be null).

Comment: Not only for ManyToMany but also usable for OneToMany. And maybe we should add `where TKey: class` so its clearer that it should be a property and not a expression or sthg like that. At first I wrote `x => x.TargetCountry.Id == ...` and that's a bool and does not work correctly of course.

Comment: Is this work for many to many with additional column s?

Comment: To echo @IvanStoev, the key is the `Include` call (and then change `FindAsync` to a `Where` + `FirstOrDefault` call).  When included, efcore will automatically delete the list before writing it again.  While the solution above is clever, it might not be necessary.

Comment: There are redy-made extension methods IEnumerable.ExceptBy() in .Net 7

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the LINQ hell in the above answer, the templated "Except" method can be rewritten as such:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> LeftComplementRight<TEntity, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TEntity> left,
        IEnumerable<TEntity> right,
        Func<TEntity, TKey> keyRetrievalFunction)
    {
        var leftSet = left.ToList();
        var rightSet = right.ToList();

        var leftSetKeys = leftSet.Select(keyRetrievalFunction);
        var rightSetKeys = rightSet.Select(keyRetrievalFunction);

        var deltaKeys = leftSetKeys.Except(rightSetKeys);
        var leftComplementRightSet = leftSet.Where(i => deltaKeys.Contains(keyRetrievalFunction.Invoke(i)));
        return leftComplementRightSet;
    }
```

Furthermore the UpdateManyToMany method can be updated to include entities that have been modified as such:

```
public void UpdateManyToMany<TDependentEntity, TKey>(
        IEnumerable<TDependentEntity> dbEntries,
        IEnumerable<TDependentEntity> updatedEntries,
        Func<TDependentEntity, TKey> keyRetrievalFunction)
        where TDependentEntity : class
    {
        var oldItems = dbEntries.ToList();
        var newItems = updatedEntries.ToList();
        var toBeRemoved = oldItems.LeftComplementRight(newItems, keyRetrievalFunction);
        var toBeAdded = newItems.LeftComplementRight(oldItems, keyRetrievalFunction);
        var toBeUpdated = oldItems.Intersect(newItems, keyRetrievalFunction);

        this.Context.Set<TDependentEntity>().RemoveRange(toBeRemoved);
        this.Context.Set<TDependentEntity>().AddRange(toBeAdded);
        foreach (var entity in toBeUpdated)
        {
            var changed = newItems.Single(i => keyRetrievalFunction.Invoke(i).Equals(keyRetrievalFunction.Invoke(entity)));
            this.Context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(changed);
        }
    }
```

which uses another custom templated "Intersect" function to find the intersection of the two sets:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> Intersect<TEntity, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TEntity> left,
        IEnumerable<TEntity> right,
        Func<TEntity, TKey> keyRetrievalFunction)
    {
        var leftSet = left.ToList();
        var rightSet = right.ToList();

        var leftSetKeys = leftSet.Select(keyRetrievalFunction);
        var rightSetKeys = rightSet.Select(keyRetrievalFunction);

        var intersectKeys = leftSetKeys.Intersect(rightSetKeys);
        var intersectionEntities = leftSet.Where(i => intersectKeys.Contains(keyRetrievalFunction.Invoke(i)));
        return intersectionEntities;
    }
```