# EntityFramework Core 2.0.1 Many-to-many, why does update not work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement function that update my entities in relation of many-to-many – `remove or insert`. I have to models - User can be in multiple conferences, Conference can have multiple users.
I am using EntityFramework Core 2.0.1. Because I found out that EF core 2.[x] does not yet support many to many joins I made a custom join table.

### Problem

My problem occurs when I want to insert new entities – `Attach` (after `SaveChanges()`) do not propagate any changes into database, I am not receiving any error. Deleting entities works correctly. I used thoughts about updating from this [source](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-many-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx). There is used nice extension `Except` for getting the deleted, inserted one.

---

I've found a solution on a separate thread - right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993860/entity-framework-core-update-many-to-many). Unfortunately, the result was unsuccessful, I was then given information about the primary key violation in the IdentityUserCustom table (AspNetUsers table) – used `AddRange` method for created `List` of `UserConference` This leads me to think that I was trying insert existing record, is not the problem in fact that I create the UserConference List? There may also be a similiar problem with this solution.

---

*I will shorten properties and rest of code for clarity.*

**User Entity**
*extends class IdentityUser*

```
public class IdentityUserCustom : IdentityUser
{
    public string ColorProfile { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserConference> UsersConferences { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>();

}
```

**Conference Entity**

```
public class Conference
{
    public int ConferenceId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserConference> UsersConferences { get; set; }
}
```

**Join Table**

```
public class UserConference
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityUserCustom User { get; set; }

    public int ConferenceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Conference Conference { get; set; }
}
```

**WebApi Update Method**

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<object> UpdateConference([FromBody]ConferenceViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        using (_unitOfWork)
        {
            //find conference
            var conference =
                await _unitOfWork.GetDbContext().Conferences.Include(p => p.UsersConferences)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ConferenceId == model.ConferenceId);

            if (conference != null)
            {
                var usersConferences = new List<UserConference>();

                //get UserConference from model and create collection
                if (model.UsersConferences.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var userModel in model.UsersConferences)
                    {
                        //find existing user
                        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userModel.UserName);
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            //make relationship
                            usersConferences.Add(new UserConference { Conference = conference, ConferenceId = model.ConferenceId, User = user, UserId = user.Id });
                        }
                    }

                }

                //get deleted users 
                var deletedUsers =
                    conference.UsersConferences.Except(usersConferences, p => (p.UserId, p.ConferenceId)).ToList();

                //get newly added users
                var addedUsers = usersConferences.Except(conference.UsersConferences,
                    p => (p.UserId, p.ConferenceId)).ToList();

                //remove deleted users
                foreach (var deletedUsr in deletedUsers)
                {
                    conference.UsersConferences.Remove(deletedUsr);
                }

                //add new users
                foreach (var addUsr in addedUsers)
                {
                    //check if detached
                    if (_unitOfWork.GetDbContext().Entry(addUsr).State == EntityState.Detached)
                        _unitOfWork.GetDbContext().UsersConferences.Attach(addUsr);

                    //add to existing conference
                    conference.UsersConferences.Add(addUsr);
                }

                //commit - SaveChanges()
                _unitOfWork.Commit();

            }

            //just for any response
            return "OK";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //log it
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 2 suspicious parts in your code. First is the `user` instance obtained from `_userManager` (potentially different `DbContext` than `_unitOfWork.GetDbContext()`). Second is the code that does `Attach`. Try setting **only** `UserId` of `new UserConference` and remove the code associated with `//check if detached`.

Comment: @IvanStoev You are indeed right about different DbContext `_userManager`. When I set only `UserId` and remove `attach`, add newly created `UserConference` to collection of `conference`, everything started to work. My question is.. Why `attach` didnt work in this situation? Also, Set the user received from `_userManager` as reference property inside collection tried to insert new user in database. Is it because of another DbContext mentioned before?