# Custom setter to add many-to-many relationship .net core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have three tables, which in combination represents a many-to-many relationship. that is, two tables and a joining table.

This is represented in the code the following way:

```
public partial class Test1
{
    public Test1()
    {
        Test1_Test2= new HashSet<Test1_Test2>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ..

    public virtual ICollection<Test1_Test2> Test1_Test2{ get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Test2s> Test2
    {
        get => Test1_Test2.Select(r => r.Test2).ToList();
        set => Test1_Test2 = value.Select(v => new Test1_Test2()
        {
            Test2Id = v.Id
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Test2
{
    public Test2()
    {
        Test1_Test2= new HashSet<Test1_Test2>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ..

    public virtual ICollection<Test1_Test2> Test1_Test2{ get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Test1_Test2
{
    public int Test1Id{ get; set; }
    public int Test2Id{ get; set; }

    public virtual Test1 Test1{ get; set; }
    public virtual Test2 Test2{ get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in the model for `Test1` I have added a "non-mapped" entity, which serve to respectively get the objects of Test2, without going through the joining table, and add a relationship between two entities in Test1 and Test2 in the joining table.

Here, I have successfully managed to get my `Test2` objects by using the getter, like so:

```
var variable = _context.Test1.Include(x => x.Test1_Test2).ThenInclude(x => x.Test2).Where(c => c.Id == Test1.Id);
```

Unfortunately, when I try to add a relationship in the joining table `"Test1_Test2"` through the setter, nothing really happens, this is my approach:

```
test1variable.Test2s.Add(test);
_context.Test1.Update(test1variable);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Have I used my setter incorrectly, or is there a more "correct" approach to this?

Comment: What is the definition of `test1variable.Test2s`? It does not seem to appear in the model definition you have given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that overwriting the `ICollection` in your setter breaks change tracking in EF.Core: It only tracks the original `ICollection` object, not the newly assigned one.

Instead, try to remove/add items to the tracked collection without allocating a new list. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42993990/8528014) provides an example with suitable extension methods, which should implement a very similar functionality as you tried to achieve using the custom property.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your model and requirements, for example,to add the relationship between the data with Test1 table Id 1 and the data with Test2 table Id 4 to Test1_Test2 table.

Please refer to the following code:

```
Test1 test1variable = _context.Test1.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Id == 1);
Test2 test = _context.Test2.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Id == 4);
Test1_Test2 test1_2 = new Test1_Test2 {  Test1 = test1variable, Test2 = test };
test1variable.Test1_Test2.Add(test1_2);
_context.SaveChanges();
```