# Prevent DbSet.AddRange() from modifying a local variable using .Net Core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need some guidance understanding what is going on "behind the hood" when an `addRange()` method is called on a `DbSet`.

I discovered a `DbContext` extension method which (should) easily update items in a Many-To-Many relationship. Link here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42993990/6480913.

Here's the extension just incase the question is deleted:

```
public static void TryUpdateManyToMany<T, TKey>(this DbContext db, IEnumerable<T> currentItems, IEnumerable<T> newItems, Func<T, TKey> getKey) where T : class
{
    db.Set<T>().RemoveRange(currentItems.Except(newItems, getKey));
    db.Set<T>().AddRange(newItems.Except(currentItems, getKey));
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other, Func<T, TKey> getKeyFunc)
{
    return items
        .GroupJoin(other, getKeyFunc, getKeyFunc, (item, tempItems) => new { item, tempItems })
        .SelectMany(t => t.tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty(), (t, temp) => new { t, temp })
        .Where(t => ReferenceEquals(null, t.temp) || t.temp.Equals(default(T)))
        .Select(t => t.t.item);
}
```

From what I understand, this extension method compares two collections of items and marks the ones that were removed as `Removed` and marks those that were added as `Added` in the `ChangeTracker`. However, when stepping through my code, I noticed that it was actually modifying my local variable `file.FileApprovers` with the new added values.

[image]

Notice how there are 3 items appended to the bottom of this collection with Type: `RadFX.Domain.Models.FileApprover`? Those were appended to the collection after running `TryUpdateManyToMany`. This causes an issue because now Indexes 0/2 and 1/3 are duplicates. Index 4 is the new value that was added on form submission and I need to still use `file.fileApprovers` beneath this method to see the "existing" approvers. If `AddRange()` really does append new items to a collection, why doesn't `RemoveRange()` remove the first two values then?

More context on my code:

```
// update m-2-m table when adding or remove users
db.TryUpdateManyToMany(file.FileApprovers, approvers
    .Select(x => new FileApprover
    {
        FileId = file.Id,
        Username = x.Username
    }), x => x);

// I figured that file.FileApprovers would be left unchanged so that I can
// get the usernames of the "existing approvers"
// for example, if I had 2 approvers, but added another one on form submission
// this variable should still just contain 2 approvers
// aka the items of Type: Castles.Proxies.FileApproverProxy

var existingApprovers = file.FileApprovers.Select(fa => fa.Username).ToList();
```

**FileApprover.cs**

```
// this is a join table class between files and approvers
public class FileApprover
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public virtual RtdbFile File { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The `approvers` variable used in the second argument of the `TryUpdateManyToMany()` is a `List` of `User` items that were submitted from the form:

**User.cs**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int BadgeNumber { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileApprover> FileApprovers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not in how `DbSet.AddRange` functions, but rather, in how you're calling `TryUpdateManyToMany`:

```
// update m-2-m table when adding or remove users
db.TryUpdateManyToMany(file.FileApprovers, approvers
    .Select(x => new FileApprover
    {
        FileId = file.Id,
        Username = x.Username
    }), x => x);
```

`x => x` being the problematic part. You're trying to do the join based on the reference equality of `x` rather than a given property.

Something like this should work fine:

```
// update m-2-m table when adding or remove users
db.TryUpdateManyToMany(file.FileApprovers, approvers
    .Select(x => new FileApprover
    {
        FileId = file.Id,
        Username = x.Username
    }), x => x.FileId);
```

Comment: Good catch! It shouldn't matter what property I use for reference equality (fileId or username) since both are of type `FileApprover`, correct? Just curious

Comment: @JordanLewallen that depends on what's the unique field for `FileApprover`

Comment: right, but in this case, both username and fileId make up a unique composite key

Comment: @JordanLewallen You may be able to use a Tuple for that, like `x => Tuple.Create<int, string>(x.FileId, x.Username)`