# Entity Framework Core : updating many-to-many and base model simultaneously

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I've been experimenting with EF Core and many-to-many relationships and have trouble updating the many-to-many relationship along with the base model at the same time and I cannot wrap my head around it.

The scenario is pretty much like in many other posts e.g. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993860/entity-framework-core-update-many-to-many).

Here are my simplified model classes:

```
public class Singer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public ICollection<SingerChoir> SingerChoirs {get; set;}
}

public class Choir
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
 
    public ICollection<SingerChoir> ChoirSingers {get; set;}
}
```

And the common class for the relation

```
public class SingerChoir
{
    public int SingerId {get;set;}
    public int ChoirId {get;set;}
    public Singer Singer {get;set;}
    public Choir Choir {get;set;}
}
```

So far this is pretty straight forward, updating a person works and updating the relationship works, too. I use this snipped (copied for better readability from the above mentioned post):

```
public static void TryUpdateManyToMany<T, TKey>(this DbContext db, IEnumerable<T> currentItems, IEnumerable<T> newItems, Func<T, TKey> getKey) where T : class
{
    db.Set<T>().RemoveRange(currentItems.Except(newItems, getKey));
    db.Set<T>().AddRange(newItems.Except(currentItems, getKey));
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other, Func<T, TKey> getKeyFunc)
{
    return items
        .GroupJoin(other, getKeyFunc, getKeyFunc, (item, tempItems) => new { item, tempItems })
        .SelectMany(t => t.tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty(), (t, temp) => new { t, temp })
        .Where(t => ReferenceEquals(null, t.temp) || t.temp.Equals(default(T)))
        .Select(t => t.t.item);
}
```

```
var model = _db.Singers
    .Include(x => x.SingerChoirs)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.SingerId== vm.Singer.SingerId);

_db.TryUpdateManyToMany(model.PersonGroups, vm.GroupsSelected
    .Select(x => new SingerChoir
    {
        ChoirId= x,
        SingerId= vm.Singer.SingerId
    }), x => x.ChoirId);
```

The problem I face is when I try updating the model and the relations **at the same time**. The use case is that there is a edit page that allows to alter the model details like the name,  but at the same time allows to see/edit the relations. I only want to send a single update request to the controller that should then handle the update in one go.

The edit page posts back a `Singer` object including the `SingerChoir` relation as this is returned by the view.

Here is the full controller code:

```
public async Task<Singer> UpdateChoirMemberships(Singer singer)
{
   var selectedSingerChoirs = singer.SingerChoirs.Select(sc => sc.ChoirId).ToList();
   var model = _ctx.Singers.AsNoTracking().Include(s => s.SingerChoirs).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == singer.Id);

   if (model != null)
   {
       _ctx.Singers.Update(singer);             
       _ctx.TryUpdateManyToMany(model.SingerChoirs, selectedSingerChoirs
                    .Select(x => new SingerChoir
                    {
                        ChoirId = x,
                        SingerId = model.Id
                    }), x => x.ChoirId);

       await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None);
       return singer;
   }
   else
      throw new InvalidDataException($"Unable to find singer with ID: {singer.Id}");
}
```

The error I getis:

> The instance of entity type 'Singer' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I do understand that I somehow do this wrong for EF core and that the singer is tracked multiple times,  but I don't understand where exactly the problem is and what to do to avoid it. I tried switching the order of `.Update` and `.TryUpdate`. In both cases the latter statement causes the issues.

Can someone point out to me what I am doing wrong exactly?

Thank you!