# Updating many-to-many links with direct relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 5 in a .NET 5.0 web app. I have two classes that are joined in a many-to-many relationship. I am using 'direct' approach, as described [here](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/updating-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-5-and-above/#direct-many-to-many-setup-normal-setup). This mean that I do not have joining tables explicitly defined in code; instead, EF has inferred the relationship from the following schema:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to be able to update a 'Group' or 'User' by simply providing EF with a new object. For example, if I provide EF with a 'Group' object that has the same ID as a Group already in the database, but it now has an extra 'User' in the Users collection, then I would expect EF to update the 'UserGroup' table that it has made behind the scenes with a new record to represent this relationship.

Here is what I have tried:

1.

```
    public void Update(Group group)
    {
        Group oldGroup = _context.Groups
            .Include(g => g.Users)
            .First(g => g.ID == group.ID);

        _context.Entry(oldGroup).CurrentValues.SetValues(group);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Result: Saves changes to any props belonging to the Group object, but does not affect any relationships.

2.

```
    public void Update(Group group)
    {
        Group oldGroup = _context.Groups
            .Include(g => g.Users)
            .First(g => g.ID == group.ID);

        oldGroup.Users = group.Users;

        _context.Entry(oldGroup).CurrentValues.SetValues(group);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Result: Exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'
```

3. 

I added some extension methods for Intersect and LeftComplementRight from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993860/entity-framework-core-update-many-to-many) and tried calculating the diffs myself.

```
    public void Update(Group group)
    {
        Group oldGroup = _context.Groups
            .Include(g => g.Users)
            .First(g => g.ID == group.ID);

        var oldUsers = oldGroup.Users;
        var newUsers = group.Users;

        var toBeRemoved = oldUsers.LeftComplementRight(newUsers, x => x.ID);
        var toBeAdded = newUsers.LeftComplementRight(oldUsers, x => x.ID);
        var toBeUpdated = oldUsers.Intersect(newUsers, x => x.ID);

        foreach (var u in toBeAdded)
        {
            oldGroup.Users.Add(u);
        }

        foreach (var u in toBeRemoved)
        {
            oldGroup.Users.Remove(u);
        }

        _context.Entry(oldGroup).CurrentValues.SetValues(group);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Result: Same exception as above.
**It was at this point I realised that the 'User' objects that compose the 'Users' collection had the 'Groups' object instantiated and populated with self-references back to the Group object.** I realised that this was probably confusing EF, so I tried this:

4.

```
    public void Update(Group group)
    {
        Group oldGroup = _context.Groups
            .Include(g => g.Users)
            .First(g => g.ID == group.ID);

        var oldUsers = oldGroup.Users;
        var newUsers = group.Users;

        var toBeRemoved = oldUsers.LeftComplementRight(newUsers, x => x.ID);
        var toBeAdded = newUsers.LeftComplementRight(oldUsers, x => x.ID);
        var toBeUpdated = oldUsers.Intersect(newUsers, x => x.ID);

        foreach (var u in toBeAdded)
        {
            u.Groups = null;
            oldGroup.Users.Add(u);
        }

        foreach (var u in toBeRemoved)
        {
            u.Groups = null;
            oldGroup.Users.Remove(u);
        }

        _context.Entry(oldGroup).CurrentValues.SetValues(group);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**This works**, however it seems like I'm doing far too much work. I anticipate having multiple many-to-many relationships throughout this project, and I don't want to have to duplicate this code on every update method. I suppose I could create an Extension method, but I feel like EF should be able to handle this common usecase.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Too many words  so I  can't understand what is your problem. Do you want to add new user to the group   or you remove a user from the group? there is no any another choises

Comment: Add or remove, or neither. Look at the code under 4. This is what I am trying to achieve, but I am looking for a better way to do it.

Comment: it  happens not very often, since I like simple decisions. So I usually just remove all  old users from the group and after this add all users from the new group. I don't care if some of the users can intersected since it is the most reliable and simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Basically just replaces the entities (the ones with matching IDs) with the currently tracked instances. The new entities in the list are automatically persisted when you save. And the entities which were present in the original list but aren't present in the new list, will be automatically removed.

```csharp
public void Update(Group updatedGroup)
{
    Group group = _context.Groups
        .Include(g => g.Users)
        .First(g => g.ID == updatedGroup.ID);

    group.Users = updatedGroup.Users
        .Select(u => group.Users.FirstOrDefault(ou => ou.ID == u.ID) ?? u)
        .ToList();

    // Do other changes on group as needed.

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Yeah, it's kind of ridiculous that there is no simple method to replace a list of entities in this way. Although it gets *less ridiculous* if you consider that normally we don't even get entity instances in our update-like methods, because usually we get the changes through DTOs, so we couldn't just replace a list to begin with.

Let me know if it doesn't work (it's late here). :)

Comment: Thanks, this works. I still have to iteratively set the 'Groups' property of all the nested User objects in 'updatedGroup' to null, but I realise that this is a problem with how I'm obtaining the updated Group, not with EF.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Although I did test it of course. :) First I was trying to make use of the RemoveRange/UpdateRange methods, but had no luck with those.

Comment: Maybe `ChangeTracker.TrackGraph` would be easier to use. Update the group, attach all the Users...